# Zoom out an image with java

Tags: java, image-processing, image-manipulation

I have a program whereby the user will enter the url for a picture, then a program in java should zoom out the picture with a width and height which are both multiple of 135px.
Can someone help??

for e.g. this is an image 1100X1121 
[image]

but i want width and the height of the image to become both multiple of 135 and less than 700px as below, now the image is 675X675 which is both a multiple of 135px and less than 700px:

[image]

Comment: Your problem description is not that helpful. What have you tried? What is your exact problem?

Comment: For e.g. if a url enters the url of picture which is 137px by 138px. Then, i want to zoom out the picture to get the same image stretch or anyway in a size 135px by 135px;

Comment: Do you want to create a thumbnail, that always has the dimensions 135x135 px^2?

Comment: +1 for the courageous choice of sample image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using [java-image-scaling-library](http://code.google.com/p/java-image-scaling/) for scaling and it works fine. It makes it easier to determine the width and/or height of the new image.

(Note that it is most often called "scaling")

Answer (score 2):

You can try this simple Java library: [Imgscalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/)

Or is your problem to determine the dimensions of new image?

Comment: Adding to what Nightsorrow linked, imgscalr will also keep your image dimensions intact, so you can just give it a width or height and have it fit the image to the dimension you choose or automatically decide based on the image's orientation. So instead of calculating the perfect dimensions, just calculate the width you want (for example) and pass it to: Scalr.resize(image, width);